# Transfer private key pair from firefox to Internet Explorer?

Tags: firefox, windows-8, internet-explorer, transfer, private-key

I'm doing some Integration testing through a VPN connection. In order to access the VPN I had to create a private/public keypair. I did this in firefox and can access the VPN.

The problem is, after we were set up on firefox we discovered that some of the required software only works on Internet Explorer. I tried to generate a new keypair through Internet Explorer but I am getting an error stating that I already have an issued key.

Is there a way of transferring private keys between browsers?

I'm using Windows 8 and need to transfer the private key from Firefox to Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a way, Firefox uses its internal certificate store and Internet Explorer uses Windows' one.

- In Firefox go to Options -> Advanced -> Encryption, there click on "View Certificates".

[image: View Certificates]

- There go to "Your Certificates" and select the one you want to export, once selected click on backup.
- Set a name and a password, the password is used when importing the private part of the key.
- You'll end up with a PKCS12 file, double click to import it into Windows; it'd be accessible from Internet Explorer then.

You can handle certificates in your machine by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog and type `certmgr.msc`. There you can delete, or move certificates among categories.

[image: Certificates Manager]

Comment: Excellent..I ended up getting my own key revoked and got issued a new one but other people can follow this method..Thank you